# Can a page have multiple ScriptManagers? If yes then under what condition will it be required?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

Can a page have multiple ScriptManagers? If yes then under what condition will it be required ?

Answer (score 7):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) says no, you can't have more than one (emphasis mine):

> **A page can contain only one ScriptManager  control in its hierarchy.** To register services and scripts for nested pages, user controls, or components when the parent page already has a ScriptManager control, use the ScriptManagerProxy  control. For more information, see Using the ASP.NET UpdatePanel Control with Master Pages

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one ASP ScriptManager at once.

You can have an ASP ScriptManager and a ScriptManager for a 3rd party control at the same time....but if it's a 'good' 3rd party control, it should have all the functionality to replace the ASP ScriptManager completely.  i.e. Telerik's RadScriptManager.